# Android Facebook authentication native vs web

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using the main Facebook example for Android integration, but i've hit a few kinks.

When i do have the native FB installed and I try to run this code as my app:

```
package com.greatapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this,  new String[] {"email", "publish_checkins"}, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

the screen just switches to the Facebook screen, and then gets back to my app without asking me to deal with permissions. It does ask me to log in in case i'm not logged in.

Without the native app installed, I do get the webview popup if you will, and i am presented with installing the app and allowing permissions.

Any reason why there's a difference?

EDIT: Guide page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Comment: That's because when you have the native Facebook, your session remains active and is shared with every official SDK app. When you don't have the native FAcebook app installed on your device, the SDK conveniently fallbacks to a webview. Permissions are used in the same way in both situations, you just need to provide them on your authorize() method as you are showing in the example.